# C++ Grade Calculator Issue

Tags: c++

I need help trying to find out the problem to my Grade calculator.  The program works as the user inserts their letter grade, such as "A or a" the output is 4.0.  But the problem I am having an issue with is when the user inserts a "A+ or A-" the "+ or - add's a 0.3 or -0.3 to their letter grade" it does not add the value of the PLus or Minus.

Here is what I have:

```
const double Plus = 0.3;
const double Minus = 0.3;



/**
 * Letter grades are A, B, C, D, and F, possibly followed by + or –. 
 * Their numeric values are 4, 3, 2, 1, and 0. In our scheme, there is no F+ or F–, 
 * or A+. Adding a + to the grade increases the numeric value by 0.3, a – decreases it 
 * by 0.3.
 *
 * Input: The letter of Grade with + or -.
 * Output: The value of inserted grade.
 *
 * @param cin the standard input stream.
 * @param cout the standard output stream.
 * @return 0 for success.
 */
int run(istream& cin, ostream& cout)
{
    // Enter your letter grade: C+
    //Grade value is[2.3]
    char list [26] = { "A, B, C, D, F, a, b, c, f" };
    char grade;
    double value;

    cout << "Enter your letter grade: ";
    cin >> grade;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(1);

    if ((grade == 'A' || grade == 'a')){
        value = 4.0;
    }
    else if ((grade == 'A+') || (grade == 'a+')){
        value = 4.0 + 0.3;
    }
    else if (grade == 'A-' || grade == 'a-'){
        value = (4.0 - Minus);
    }
    else if (grade == 'B' || grade == 'b'){
        value = 3.0;
        if (grade == 'B+' || grade == 'b+'){
            value = (3.0 + Plus);
        }
        else if (grade == 'B-' || grade == 'b-'){
            value = (3.0 - Minus);
        }
    }
    else if (grade == 'C' || grade == 'c'){
        value = 2.0;
        if (grade == 'C+' || grade == 'c+'){
            value = (2.0 + Plus);
        }
        else if (grade == 'C-' || grade == 'c-'){
            value = (2.0 - Minus);
        }
    }
    else if (grade == 'D' || grade == 'd'){
        value = 1.0;
        if (grade == 'D+' || grade == 'd+'){
            value = (1.0 + Plus);
        }
        else if (grade == 'D-' || grade == 'd-'){
            value = (1.0 - Minus);
        }
    }
    else if (grade == 'F' || grade == 'f'){
        value = 0.0;
        if (grade == 'F+' || grade == 'f+'){
            value = (0.0 + Plus);
        }
        else if (grade == 'F-' || grade == 'f-'){
            value = (0.0 - Minus);
        }
    }
    else if (!(grade == list[26])){
        cout << "INVALID LETTER GRADE" << endl;
        value = 0;
    }

    cout << "Grade value is [" << value << "]" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char grade` so it will only capture `A` in **A+**. You need to work on that..

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled. How many characters is A+ ?

Comment: better to use switch case.. too many errors... your code will never check + or -

Comment: Your note is: `'f-'`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it simple:

Your problem is that grade is a `char` and cannot store `'A+'` (2 chars: 'A','+').
Change `char grade` to `std::string grade` (remember to include `<string>`) and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `A+` or `A-` is two characters, and so cannot be stored in a single `char` variable. You can either use two variables (although this could be problematic if you didn't input a `+` or `-`, as there would be nothing to store in the second variable) or use a `std::string` to store whatever is inputted, and then check to see if there's a `+` or `-` in that.

Also, as a simplification for all your `if` statements, you can use a switch-case block, or use this trick to get the grade point directly from the letter grade.

For capital letters:    `gradePoint = 4.0 - (letter - 'A')`

For lower case letters: `gradePoint = 4.0 - (letter - 'a')`

Just note that you'll have to include a separate check for and `F`, due to `E` being skipped with grades.